# Automating query export to Excel from Access with linked tables to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, vba

I'm trying to automate exporting of query results from Access 2010 to Excel 2010. It is not easy because Access is using linked tables (SQL Server 2008 R2). I know that is can be done manually but I would really like to automate this process.

When I tried to step though the following VBA code located in Access, I get to this line and then it just running and running and never gets past this point

```
Set wbTarget = XL.Workbooks.Open("H:\TATData\Test.xlsx")
```

(no error messages)

I've tested the query before I copied it into the VBA Editor, so I know the query works and it's very fast, but not with automation. I also set up MS Excel library in Access that is needed.

Please help to figure out what needs to be done to get this to work.
I had to kill Access to get it to stop running.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Sub ExportToExcel()

'Step 1: Declare your variables

Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim excelApp    As Object

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim qdfTestData As QueryDef


Dim rsTestData As Recordset

Dim strSQL As String

Dim i As Integer


strSQL = "SELECT dbo_Patient.firstnm, dbo_Patient.lastnm, dbo_Sample.SampleDt, dbo_Test.TestTypeCd "
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM (dbo_Patient INNER JOIN dbo_Sample ON dbo_Patient.PatientId = dbo_Sample.PatientId) INNER JOIN dbo_Test ON dbo_Sample.SampleID = dbo_Test.SampleId "
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE (((dbo_Test.TestTypeCd)='FL_XM_ALLO'));"


'set up reference to the query to export
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete ("qrTest")

'set up reference to the query to export

Set qdfTestData = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("qrTest", strSQL)

'Execute the query
Set rsTestData = qdfTestData.OpenRecordset()


'Create a new Excel instance.
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Set reference to the export workbook
'Set wbTarget = XL.Workbooks.Open("H:\TATData\Test.xlsx")
Set wbTarget = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
Set sht = wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'clear excel sheet
On Error GoTo 0

    excelApp.Visible = True

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents
'Use paste from recordset to put in excel sheet
wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsTestData
'clear excel sheet

Errorhandler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Exit Sub
'wbTarget.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: please see the updated code above.  I now get error '430' Class doesn't not support automation. Is there any hope to get this to work? Thx

Comment: it goes to the error handler, so perhaps `excelApp.Visible = True`..If i remove the error handler it stops at `wbTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsTestData` with error 430 message.

Comment: yes, it does and it opens it fine... it just doesn't copy the data.

Comment: I have my doubts that you can pass a recordset created in Access to the Excel method `CopyFromRecordset`. Wouldn't you have to create the recordset via the `XL` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this in a more difficult way than necessary. To directly export your query `qrTest`, use

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qrTest", _
    "H:\TATData\Test.xlsx", True
```

(this will create an unformatted sheet)
or

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qrTest", acFormatXLSX, "H:\TATData\Test.xlsx", False
```

(this will create a formatted sheet)

---

Side note: If

```
Set wbTarget = XL.Workbooks.Open("H:\TATData\Test.xlsx")
```

doesn't work, this cannot be caused by your query or anything in Access. Does this file itself have any ODBC connections?

Comment: do I need to delete the rebuild the query each time? ..The Excel file is not connected.  Do I need to connect it to make this work?  Do you have an idea what is causing the automation error '430'? Thank you much  for your help!

Comment: 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "qrTest", _
    "H:\TATData\Test.xlsx", True` should this code be in a regular Access module?  Please explain where to put the code and how to call it. Thx

Comment: @user3781528: It doesn't really matter. If your SQL SELECT is static, you could also save it as a "regular" query (perhaps with a better name than `qrTest`), and export that one.

Comment: @user3781528: You set up your SELECT query, either static or dynamic as you have it now. Then you do `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`. All your Excel code can be removed.

Comment: lol...I can't believe how easy it is...it worked...thank you so much

Comment: is there a way to specify which sheet I want to copy the data to?

Comment: @user3781528: No, `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` always creates a new workbook with a single sheet. You can open the workbook afterwards with VBA and add / rename sheets.